# TextInputLayout - boxBackgroundColor style property not working in Android

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I am using an Outlined text input layout in my application. I want to change the background color on focus, but I wasn't able to achieve it using `boxBackgroundColor` style property. My layout and style codes are added below:

**Layout**

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_username"
    style="@style/TextInputLoginTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:hintTextColor="@color/login_hint_color">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        style="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox.Dense"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:textColor="#38465A"
        android:inputType="text"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Theme**

```xml
<style name="TextInputLoginTheme" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/login_outlined_stroke_color</item>
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/login_box_background_color</item>
    <item name="boxBackgroundMode">outline</item>
</style>
```

**login_box_background_color**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_focused="true" />
   <item android:color="#EFF2F5" android:state_hovered="true" />
   <item android:color="#EFF2F5" android:state_enabled="false" />
   <item android:color="#EFF2F5" />
</selector>
```

**Material dependency**

```groovy
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
```

The background color is not changing to white on focus.

Comment: Um, have you tried to use your style resource in `android:theme` attribute instead of `style` ? Usually color changes require the `android:theme` attribute to be used.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul: My requirement is to update a material design style, how to move that to the theme? Could you please provide a sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background color is only supported for filled boxes. When used with box variants other than BOX_BACKGROUND_FILLED, the box background color may not work as intended.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#setboxbackgroundcolor)

`app:boxBackgroundMode="filled"` // Added

My Alternative Solution;

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_username"
            style="@style/TextInputLoginTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="filled"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/login_hint_color">
```

Comment: I want to keep the outlined box. So, my requirement can't be achieved using this method.
I am marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Is this still not fixed or allowed?